# No sound, recent Debian 11 upgrade, NVidia sound card

Tags: debian, sound-card, firmware

I'm a relative newbie with Debian and I hope someone can help me with my problem:

I've recently installed Debian 10 on my Dell G3 15 3590. I've tried downloading all the necessary firmware for the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti video card.

After downloading, updating and upgrading, along with the new firmware (and to my surprise), the OS was upgraded to Debian 11 as well.

I've spent a great deal of time downloading and configuring everything, and just as I launched a game on Steam to test the new video card firmware, I noticed that THERE WAS NO SOUND. When I turn the sound up or down I see the sound level display showing a message that says "Dummy Output" as well.

I've tried looking for a solution, but I found nothing that worked. I'll use some info I've found in this link to provide with information. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468071/no-sound-dummy-output-on-debian-9-fresh-install

Hope someone can get me out of this one. Cheers

```
~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


~$ pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xa30d0000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1aeb"
        device.product.name = "TU116 High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "TU116 High Definition Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"


~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A1 Audio
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:1aeb] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell TU116 High Definition Audio Controller [1028:0949]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel


~$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_soc_dmic           16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   151552  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_sof_pci            24576  0
snd_sof_intel_byt      24576  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   102400  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               139264  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_skl           180224  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        36864  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    45056  3 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_sof,dell_laptop
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
snd_soc_acpi           16384  4 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_intel          57344  1
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_skl
soundwire_intel        45056  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_soc_core          315392  6 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_soc_dmic
snd_compress           32768  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec         172032  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core          110592  10 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               135168  10 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              49152  1 snd_pcm
snd                   110592  12 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd


~$ groups yo
yo : yo cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev bluetooth lpadmin scanner
```

Comment: Graphics cards don’t need firmware but drivers, but whatever. // How are your speakers connected? 3.5mm jack, HDMI receiver, …?

Comment: What do you mean? My laptop's got its in-built speakers... I don't know how they're connected to the sound card/motherboard.... It's got the 3.5mm jack for output and an HDMI slot as well..